# Simple_form form-horizontal still doesn't work in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to get simple_form with form-horizontal working after a `bundle update`: The layout is not horizontal anymore :(

I've read and tried http://www.iconoclastlabs.com/blog/using-twitter-bootstrap-3-with-simple_form and [Simple_form class form-horizontal with bootstrap 3 not working in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811407/simple-form-class-form-horizontal-with-bootstrap-3-not-working-in-rails-4). The latter claims, that simple_form 3.1.0 is working with bootstrap 3, but here it doesn't :(

The problem might be, that the  around the input element is simply missing:

```
<div class="form-group string required container_code">
    <label class="string required col-lg-2 control-label control-label" for="container_code"><abbr title="Benötigt">*</abbr> Nummer</label>
    <input class="string required form-control form-control" id="container_code" name="container[code]" type="text" value="1" />
</div>
```

At least, the example from here looks quite different: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php

These are the gem versions that I'm currently using:

- twitter-bootstrap-rails (3.2.1 cd805c7)
- simple_form (3.1.0)
- rails (4.0.0)

As I'm quite a rails rookie, I was hoping that bootstrap and simpleform can help me to *avoid* such problems, so I really hope you can help me...

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try as the outer div:

```
<div class="form-inline">
  Your form code here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but with this it looks actually worse :s It's not all on its own line anymore, but now labels and inputs run into each other...

Comment: Okay. Then, I think I'm not sure what you mean by horizontal form. You should probably post an image of what you have versus what you want to see so it's easier for someone to help..